# how to write xsd for following XML requirement

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have the following xml for which I need XSD.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Metadata>
  <Field Name="Claim Number">100</Field>
  <Field Name="Audit Year">2010</Field>
  <Field Name="Auditor Name">ABC PQR</Field>
</Metadata>
```

in the above xml if I delete `<Field Name="Audit Year">2010</Field>` this line then it must say "Audit Year" is not present in the given XML.

below is the present XSD but it's not a proper way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
<xs:simpleType name="temp" >
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:enumeration value="Audit Year" />
</xs:restriction>
```

```
<xs:element name="Metadata">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Field">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
           <xs:attribute name="Name" type="temp" use="required"/>
           <!--<xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="optional" />-->
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:schema>
```

Comment: You forgot to show us the XSD you currently have.

Comment: @ Mathias Müller Thanks for showing the interest in my question. I have added my current XSD please help me.

Comment: Can you post your whole XSD?  there are definitely some missing tags here.

Comment: @DanField I have posted the whole XSD there is no missing tags. It's properly working but what approach I took for my question to create XSD is may be wrong. So any suggestion is more appriciable.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to rename each `Field name="X"` element as `X`, so your XML is

```
<Metadata>
  <ClaimNumber>100</ClaimNumber>
  <AuditYear>2010</AuditYear>
  <Auditor>ABC PQR</Auditor>
</Metadata>
```

Now the task is trivial.